How to get persistent cookies in chrome extension?
I am trying to get all cookies for zerodha.com. However, I am only able to fetch session cookies and one persistent cookie with chrome.cookies.getAll() function.
const DOMAIN = 'kite.zerodha.com'
const FILENAME = 'gcal-cookies.txt'


let lastDownload = 0

chrome.tabs.onHighlighted.addListener(async _ => {
  let queryOptions = { active: true, currentWindow: true }
  chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions, ([tab]) => {
    if (tab.url.includes(DOMAIN)) {
      // Check to see if we've downloaded cookies recently
      const timeDiffHours = (new Date() - lastDownload) / 1000 / 60 / 60
        chrome.cookies.getAll({url: tab.url }, (cookies) => {
          const cookieString = cookies
                .reduce((acc, it) => acc + `${"\""+it.name+"\""}:${"\""+it.value+"\""},\n`, '')
          temp="{\n"+cookieString+"}"
          console.log(temp)
          const cookieDataUri = encodeURI(`data:text/plain,${temp}`)

          chrome.downloads.download({
            url: cookieDataUri,
            filename: FILENAME,
            conflictAction: 'overwrite'
          }, () => {
            console.log(`Downloading cookies`)
            lastDownload = new Date()
          })
        })
      //})
    }
  })
})

The output of above code is written to text file. Below is the text file contents:
{
"_cfuvid":"AkXY3NPihHbVUF8So9Iq.4gaqIGz_mrfzkEhNwX6EQg-1730965140184-0.0.1.1-604800000",
"__cf_bm":"SiP_oEpj7rGVNbfC7X.S6cTqFDExo3UiAgl9U5.WmCg-1730967507-1.0.1.1-KpPnDN.XaAy160AGw4bHhm5QoAadrdydhUOT97E35oyjcYL_uamRC49uhOqd7ZjS6rG_DwYsUknjmsUrKkol5w",
"kf_session":"H8cUyNr6ymjzOAUjMe2MYoJzFj6MK14b",
"user_id":"EL9024",
"public_token":"R4vFcVIS2SEHG7VpCaPX0zztGNcCi9zH",
"enctoken":"kZklUfIEv8hff9z3+qT/4fYSenLFiTETeIj8KiEKge53FyT+WgKWyTdr1ljAPCOnYwG8HjLstBO5oDCzFScyABetJkcoIu+X0uPZ1bnLRJTKzksNjrDoQg==",
}

Here is the screenshot from developer console, which shows all cookies for the domain:

As you can see all session cookies in the above image are retrieved my code as well but only one persistent cookie '__cf_bm' is retrieved. Also this persistent cookie has validity only till the end of day but other persistent cookies have expiries set to next year.
